# Prove that $X_{t}$, the set of $n\times m$ matrices of rank at most $t$ with entries in $k$ is an algebraic subset of $k^{n\times m}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following problem,

> Prove that $X_{t}$, the set of $n\times m$ matrices of rank at most
>   $t$ with entries in $k$ is an algebraic subset of $k^{n\times m}$

I understand that I have to find set of polynomial equations in $n\times m$ variable such that $X_{t}$ is the zero set of those equations.

Any idea, how should I start constructing such equations ?

Comment: What would you do if $m=n$ and $t=n-1$?

Comment: Hint: What does it mean $\mathrm{rank}M\leq t-1$, for $M\in\mathbb{K}^n_m$?